# Why doesn't let me access to the other javascript functions Vue Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I found a code on the internet that used a class that did not say if Vue or JS so I put it to test, the problem is that it does not let me enter any function importing the class and nothing.

I thought it would be a good way to refactor the error messages that come from the backend to the component inside Laravel that is the form.

**error.js**

```
export default class Errors {
    constructor(){
        this.errors = {};
    }
    has(field){
        return this.errors.hasOwnProperty(field);
    }
    any(){
        return Object.keys(this.errors).length > 0;
    }
    get(field){
        if (this.errors[field]) {
            return this.errors[field][0];
        }
    }
    record(errors){
        this.errors = errors;
    }
    clear(field){
        delete this.errors[field];
    }
}
```

My form component

```
import Errors from '../../errors/error.js'

export default{
  data() {
        return {
            edit: false,
            formContact: [],
            errors: new Errors(),
            error: []
        };
  },
  methods: {
        updateForm(){

            axios.put(route('contact.update',this.contact['id']),this.formContact)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.errors = []
                    console.log(res)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    if(err.response.status === 422){
                        this.errors = err.response.data.errors || {}
                        console.log(this.errors.get('linkedin')) //not work
                    }
                })
        }
  }
```

Message error: caught (in promise) TypeError: _this3.errors.get is not a function

I hope to be able to make the Errors class work outside of my form component so that it can be refactored.

Comment: Isn't `this.errors = err.response.data.errors || {}` overwriting your `Errors` instance? `this.errors` is no longer an instance of your `Errors` class, it is just a plain object/array from the json response. I'm assuming you want something like `this.errors.record(err.response.data.errors || {})`.

Comment: I think what you were trying to do was in your catch block setting `this.errors.record(err.response.data)` instead of overwriting your `Errors` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defaulting `this.errors` to be a `new Errors` instance, but then you're overwriting this instance in your axios callback. `this.errors = err.response.data.errors || {}` is overwriting your `Errors` instance, not updating it.

You'll want to use the `record()` method on your `Errors` instance to update your `Errors` instance with the set of errors that came back from the request.

```
if (err.response.status === 422) {
    this.errors.record(err.response.data.errors || {})
    console.log(this.errors.get('linkedin'))
}
```